# Phonegap WP8 and GWT

Tags: cordova, gwt, windows-phone-8

I am trying to make a GWT application work on a WP8 device using phone gap but to no success.
The onModuleLoad is never called.

When I just put a plain html file in the www directory of the wp8 platform it displays and runs just fine on a wp8 device.

A GWT website however just gives a white screen. When I put a Window.alert at the first line of the onModuleLoad it never gets called.

The GWT app runs fine using Phonegap on iOS and Android...

The HTML code I have is only :

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Jqm</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="jqm/jqm.nocache.js?r=20140916"></script>    
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>   
        </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in Java GWT I only have

```
public void onModuleLoad()
{
   Window.alert("onModuleLoad");
   RootLayoutPanel.get().add(new Label("test"));
}
```

Only thing in phonegap I did was : phonegap platform add wp8... Put the output of the GWT compiler in the www directory of WP8 platform. And try to run in VS2013.
I also tried it by putting the generated gwt www code in the main www folder of the phonegap structure. And then doing a "phonegap emulate wp8" (this is the way I always use for Android). 
But both failing.

If I add a script tag to the head to listen for phonegap to become ready it does become ready... But not entering onModuleLoad ever...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the use of Window.alert

see 
[Windows Phone 7 and 8 Quirks for notification](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert_windows_phone_7_and_8_quirks)

When phonegap becomes ready you should be able to dummy up alert with

```
window.alert = navigator.notification.alert;
```

as suggested but until then Window.alert will throw an exception